# Is it possible to create custom directives in svelte?

Tags: svelte

I know there are slots and some discussion about [slots without DOM elements](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2080). What about custom directives? (That is, special "atributes" that will modify the behavior of a component/DOM element)

Comment: You might want to look into [`actions`](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/adding-parameters-to-actions) which can be used on an element.

Answer (score 9):

There are no custom *directives* just yet like you might find in Vue, but you can certainly bind actions to child elements with `use:something`. See the docs [here](https://svelte.dev/docs#use_action). You can also find an official example [here](https://svelte.dev/examples#actions).

Here's a small example:

```
<button on:click={doSomething} use:tooltip={calculatedTooltip}>
    Click Me
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Coming from an Angular background, I wondered the same. I was happy to see there's [something similar](https://svelte.dev/docs#use_action) in Svelte thanks to `GoogleMac`'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58663771/2419808).

If you are used to Angular, you'd probably be looking for event dispatches too (`@Output` in Angular). It seems like there's not such a concept in Svelte's actions but you can make use of `parameters`. Here's an example:

```js
// outside-click.js => Action
export function outsideClick(node, onOutsideClick) {
  //                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ parameter
  function handleClick ({ target }) {
    const clickedOutside = !node.contains(target);

    if (clickedOutside) {
      onOutsideClick();
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

  return {
    destroy () {
      window.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    }
  };
}
```

```html
// MyComponent.svelte => component
<script>
  function hideMenu() {
    // hide menu logic
  }
</script>

<div use:outsideClick={hideMenu} class="menu">
  <!-- Menu that has to be closed when clicking outside of it -->
</div>
```

Hope this would help someone.